# How to let my visitors to listen to different online radios using flash player?

Tags: flash, streaming, audio-player, webradio

After I've found out that WMP is not best idea for Firefox users as they need to install additional plugin, I wanted to try out JW player and I googled all I could about audio streaming and flash players.

I got something like www.onlineradio.com/32.asx -> it's not on my server, it's different server, but I can't seem to find a solution to let my visitors to play this content as they wish to. It works over WMP. JW Player does not work the way I want it to work, or I might be using it wrong way.

Please, help me with this one.

edit: Is there any real reason why flash can't do this but WMP can? Isn't there any solution for both FF and IE? - of course I wouldn't contact all radios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't do it with flash unless you either set up a proxy on your web server, or you get the owners of the radio station to add your website to the crossdomain.xml file on their server.

http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14213

Comment: why can i do it with wmp then? is there any other way?

Comment: Flash has a very strict security policy which does not (by default) allow to mix content from multiple sites, unless expicitly permitted by the content provider. OTOH, WMP is not running content from your website, it just downloads parameters, so there is no mixing involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you actually are having difficulties with RTMP in general or if you actually just cannot find out 'where' to connect...

In case you cannot find the access points, you may probably start sending emails to the guys owning the radios showing your interest and asking for access information... (If you cannot find it in any FAQ, etc.). 
That's not only fair towards the providers but you will also get a clear answer. If they are used to this kind of request you may luckily get a detailed tech-specs document about their services.

Once you have the details we may be able to help you setting up a ready-built player or creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of streaming solutions are available for audio streaming
1.Icecast
2.Shoutcast
just go through these you may get the answer....
there are other commercial solutions are also available for this...
like 
1.Flash Streaming server
2.Helix Server
3.Windows media services 9
For some idea about Streaming servers you can refer
http://streamingserve.blogspot.com